# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_user_locale() in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services

As of now I have a pro version of `WP Mail SMTP`

And I successfully added that plugin to my `wp-admin`

But when I tried to deactivate the old `WP Mail SMTP` and activate my new `WP Mail SMTP Pro`

This gaves me an error like this

```
   Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_user_locale() in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/wp-mail-smtp-pro/src/Pro/activation.php:20 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php(524): WPMailSMTP\Core->{closure}('') #1 /var/www/html/wp-admin/plugins.php(166): do_action('activate_wp-mai...') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/wp-mail-smtp-pro/src/Pro/activation.php on line 20
```

How do you fix this one? I'm using AWS as my server for this Wordpress

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: Are you running the latest wordpress version? This function is specifically a wordpress defined function

Comment: Hello mokugo, Im trying to find the version of my wordpress having hard time to find it but I updated my post

Comment: Take a look at this link: https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-easily-check-which-wordpress-version-you-are-using/

Comment: WordPress 4.6.18 running Umbra Child Theme theme.

Comment: Right you're running an older version of Wordpress. Take a look at https://wordpress.org/support/article/updating-wordpress/. I believe by updating your Wordpress version you'll have access to this version. Take a backup first (either as an EBS snapshot/AMI) or as a file backup.

Comment: Will try to follow this step At least I have an idea now what to do. Will get back to this thread, for the next update

Comment: Good, if you let me know if that works I'll add it as the answer :)

Comment: Your answer helps me. If you have time to check this too it will be more helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62241527/wordpress-aws-ses-there-has-been-a-critical-error-on-your-website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to upgrade to the most recent version of Wordpress.

A legacy version was being used where the `get_user_locale` function did not exist, but a plugin expected it to be there.