# Wordpress & AWS SES : There has been a critical error on your website

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I successfully uploaded my elite version `WP Elite Mail SMTP`

As of now, I included my AWS Secret key and other credentials.

But the problem is when I tried to send test email using WP Mail SMTP that is connected to my AWS SES

Im getting an error like this

`There has been a critical error on your website`

Here's the current picture

[image]

[image]

Also the save settings missing maybe because of the error?

Tried this too

`define('WP_DEBUG', true);`

But cant find the error.

Trying to  find alternative  way since as of now I dont have the access of the email credential

In addition,

My AWS SES is out of the sandbox

also

I have 2 different correct region

West Oregon and N. Virginia

I tested my 2 different region by sending 2 different email.

I tested it inside of my AWS account when you search SES

[image]

and I'm using v5.4.1 Wordpress. Some of my plugins and themes are needed an update But the last time I update it there's a lot of error occured that's why I reverted it.

**update**

I found an error on the same page

[image]

Comment: Is your SES still in Sandbox mode? And is the region correct?

Comment: You might have better luck asking this on: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: My SES is out of the sandbox mode and I have 2 different correct region (N Virginia and Oregon)

Comment: I've updated my post I hope it gives a clue

Comment: I also ask this to wordpress.stackexchange but I'm keeping this post active so that I have 2 different options

Comment: You are seeing a cross site scripting error. May need to update your headers to handle the cross site scripting. if wordpress is hosted on aws, then there may be a waf config with the cert.

Comment: Yes it is hosted to waf config. Hmm can u give some info /tutorial about it